# OpenGL randomly slows down

Tags: visual-studio-2010, firefox, opengl

I'm currently learning OpenGL and I've noticed a rarely occuring performance problem:

My program is rather small so it's not a performance problem with the code itself, but when I'm running the code via Visual Studio I sometimes only get 1-2 FPS instead of the usual 60.
Once this happens I can restart the program as often as I want to (in debug and release mode alike) and it won't go away.

However, when I close my Firefox (or manually shut down the plugin-container.exe though task manager) and restart my program everything is fine again. After that I can start Firefox again (with the same tabs open) and the bug does not reappear.

I use the newest version of Firefox, and I've had this bug with several programs already - both made by me and others and using different versions of OpenGL. However I don't think I've had this problem when starting a compiled exe directly, but only by using the Run feature of Visual Studio.

I've searched the web but I only found a [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/performance-hit-from-plugin-container-in-firefox-823597/) about the generally bad performance of this plugin-container.

Does anyone else have this problem? Do you know any walkarounds or fixes?

PS: Regarding isti_spl's answer:
The CPU utilisation of the plugin-container.exe jumps to the 50% limit when the problem happens.
I'm working with Visual Studio, but the problem only occurs when I also have Firefox running (it most certainly is because of this plugin-container, so it probably won't happen with other browsers).
It's hard to isolate the problem because I can't replicate it. It might happen 1 out of 50 times.
I'll see if closing flash-related tabs (youtube, blip.tv etc) fixes the problem next time it happens.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue, tried reinstalling drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Can you isolate the problem? 
You first mentioned running visual studio then firefox. Please try to run separately.
Under FF. is it caused by WebGL or flash plugin? Is it caused by visiting specific sites?
Is it FF specific or happens under other browsers too?
Does CPU utilisation jump high? Please verify that too and which process consumes most CPU.

Not sure, but likely gpu driver + flash problems. 
If so, the problem is not in your code, other GL program should be affected too.